# how to pass the amount to pay and how to get transaction_id in in-app-payments sdk?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, square-connect, square

I am new to square payment. I want to integrate square payment gateway in my Android app. I tried the in-app-payments-sdk. But I couldn't find how to pass the amount to pay and how to get transaction_id in in-app-payments sdk. I am only able to input card details and getting a "nonce" in OnActivityResult. Do I have to use other APIs like Orders API or Payments API? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. Once you get the nonce:

The simplest way is to call the Payment api

1. Call the payment api or equivalent from Android SDK https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/create-payment
   `source_id` is your nonce

Alternatively,

2. You can create an order using https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/create-order

Then you can use that order_id to make a payment from step 1